# Facebook API get higher image resolution

Tags: python, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I currently use the [Python facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) to poll the facebook API to get a list of posts on a page's wall.

Very roughly the essential parts of this look like

```
import facebook

# Get access token for my app_id and secret key
ACCESS_TOKEN = facebook.get_app_access_token(app_id, app_secret_key)

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)
profile = graph.get_object(USER)  # where USER is user's page I want posts for

# grab the posts
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'feed')
```

This works well enough, but if the posts have images associated with them, the link returned to the image is typically for a `130x130` image, which is too small for my needs. As an example:

```
 u'picture': u'https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/10525675_431059123701393_2400070961435082030_n.png?oh=9a7391960a0b56341f1c927e34cd3517&oe=5436133D&__gda__=1415044571_40f45eb7ec13237c7732f99b4c284841'
```

Is there a way I can poll the API for a higher resolution version, or convert this URL to that of the higher resolution version?

(Some notes: I tried just replacing the p130xp130 --> p430x430, and it sometimes works, but not always.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed this actually, but if someone knows a better way I'd be interested in hearing it.

I essentially do:

```
# poll each post for actual source image if post is timeline photo
for post in posts:
    if post['type'] == u'photo':
        objid = post['object_id']
        picture = graph.get_object(objid)
        source = picture['source']
        # append source link to post
        post['source'] = source
```

I can now use this full resolution original URL link in the rest of my script.